# Java Melody JPA Monitoring Implementation failed for HibernatePersitenceProvider

Tags: java-melody

I followed all the steps for JPA Monitoring as mentioned in User Guide of Java Melody. However, changing my Persistence Provider from  `<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>` to `net.bull.javamelody.jpa.provider` and setting property as `<property name="net.bull.javamelody.jpa.provider" value="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider" />` didn't work for me because EclipseLink is used over Hibernate while deploying my web application. Is there any way to get past this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowhere in Java Melody's User Guide its mentioned that JNDI name for Data Source should start with 'jdbc/'. That's all I had to do for enabling JPA Monitoring. My JNDI name was `jndiName`. I created a new Custom JNDI Resource (as directed in UserGuide) in Glassfish Administration Console and named it `jdbc/jndiName`.